# How to discover the relation between 4096 and 729 as result of 10 billions of simulations.

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, relations

First of all I'm not mathematician (really admire them), but programmer. My question come from the result or analysis from `10 billions simulations` on an specific work/task.

I found that a case with `4096` possible outputs, the process only found `729` cases. This was unexpected to sense common on the task itself, so I repeat the simulation more than 10 billions times, on different ways and different RNG (random number generators) and still the numbers were the same.

My initial thought (since I'm not mathematician) was divide `4096` by `729` with no significative result (at least for me). But finally I discover that `729` is `3^6`, and as `4096` is `2^12` there should be something that make a relation between this (something that I don't know and I think I wont never discover myself because I just don't know how to begin)

So that's the reason why my question is so odd, but I'm looking for an answer on how this task can resolve only `3^6` of `2^12` cases without any error margin.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.
Please take consideration that I'm still trying learn rule of three and I'm 42yo

Comment: If you downvote me, as Im new on this stack, please consider comment in order to update my answer and improve it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this is why the question was down-voted, but it's basically impossible to say why those numbers show up unless you say something about what the task *is*. It's *possible* that (for example) there are six choices to make, each of which are nominally from four items, but only three of which are actually ever chosen, so that out of $4^6 = 4096$ possible combinations, only $3^6 = 729$ are ever chosen. But we can't tell without more information about the task.

Comment: @BrianTung it can be silly for you but I would never ever think about to find 4^6 and is totally logic what you tell me. The process is very complex I think to post it, and when I wrote the the question I was conviced myself that find a relation between 2 numbers are not impossible. Sorry! But Indeed I think you could discover an error in the whole process. I don't know what is but for sure there is something about only 3 can be chosen. Thanks a lot! If you want to write it as answer I'll glad to accept it.

Comment: I suggest that you like at one of the cases you found which the process didn't, and see if it's a valid case. If yes, why didn't your process find it? If no, what was the mistake in your resasoning>

Comment: Absolutely @CalvinLin, it was a mistake from the recopilation of the data, 1/4 data were trunked. Found the relation helps to found the error. Thanks a lot to everyone. I wont delete the question in order Brian can answer it, he deserves it, also you, thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't think your question was silly; it could just use some additional information that would help us figure out what was going on.

Comment: @BrianTung no no, I never thought it!!! Sorry for my english. I mean "it seems to be silly" but I always think "think in easy" is the hardest task to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per OP's request:

It may be significant that $4096 = 2^{12} = 4^6$, because we may then be able to interpret the situation broadly as follows:

> Suppose that the simulation involves six successive selections, each of which nominally has four possible choices. There are then $4^6 = 4096$ possible combinations in all. However, if in each selection one choice is somehow accidentally disabled, then there will only be $3^6 = 729$ combinations that will actually be generated.
>
> For instance, there are $4096$ six-digit numbers using only the digits $0, 1, 2, 3$. But if for some reason the digit $0$ is not selectable, then there are only $729$ six-digit numbers that will ever be produced.

More information about the task being simulated would make it more apparent what the situation actually is, of course.

Comment: Gotta say, great numerology from meagre data!